# Handle javascript dynamically generated controls in controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have a project in asp.net core. I have a view where I can do a paste operation from an excel table in an input and the javascript code reads the information and creates input controls with that info. How can I handle all of the controls and send them to the controller via submit? I want to save all of the info.

Javascript Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#excel").bind('paste',
        function (e) {
            $("#excel").hide();
            $("#div_cargar").hide();
            var cells = '';
            var i_group = '<div class="form-group row">';
            var f_group = '</div>';


            //Variables del input del id frente
            var i_div_1 = '<div class="col-sm-1">';
            var f_div = '</div>';
            var label_id = '<label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="id_frente">Frente:</label>';


            //variables del input de frente
            var i_div_7 = '<div class="col-sm-2">';
            var f_div_7 = '</div>';
            var label_frente = '<label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="frente">Frente:</label>';
            var copy = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
            var rows = copy.split('\n');
            var id_frente_in = '';
            var frente_in = '';
            var id_frente = "";
            var frente = "";

            //Variables partidas
            var label_partida = '<label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="frente">Partida:</label>';
            var id_partida_in = '';
            var partida_in = '';
            var partida = '';
            var id_partida = '';


            //Variables conceptos
            var i_div_2 = '<div class="col-sm-2     ">';
            var f_div_2 = '</div>';
            var i_div_3 = '<div class="col-sm-3">';
            var f_div_3 = '</div>';
            var i_div_4 = '<div class="col-sm-4">';
            var f_div_4 = '</div>';
            var label_concepto = '<label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="frente">Concepto:</label>';
            var id_concepto_in = '';
            var concepto_in = '';
            var concepto = '';
            var id_concepto = '';
            var contadorparaapartado = 0;

            //Variables parametros
            var i_div_5 = '<div class="col-sm-8">';
            var f_div_5 = '</div>';
            var label_parametro = '<label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="frente">Parametro:</label>';
            var id_concepto_in = '';
            var parametro_in = '';
            var parametro = '';
            var id_partida = '';


            var previousrow = "";
            var hr = "";
            $.each(rows,
                function (index, value) {

                    //Se valida que no este vacio el value
                    if (value) {
                        var columna = rows[index].split("\t");
                        console.log(columna);
                        columna[0] = columna[0].replace(/["]/g, "'");
                        columna[1] = columna[1].replace(/["]/g, "'");
                        //Se valida si cambia de columna

                        if (columna[0].split(".").length - 1 == 3) {//FRENTES--------------------------------------------------------
                            id_frente_in = columna[0];
                            frente_in = columna[1];
                            //Se arregla el input del id del frente
                            id_input =
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_frente" name="id_frente_ek[]" req="" value="' +
                                id_frente_in +
                                '">';
                            id_frente = label_id + i_div_1 + id_input + f_div;
                            id_frenteactual = id_frente;

                            //Se arregla el input del frente
                            frente_input =
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="frente" name="frente[]" req="" value="' +
                                frente_in +
                                '">';
                            frente = i_div_7 + frente_input + f_div_7;

                            frenteactual = id_frenteactual + frente;

                            //$('.frentes').append(id + frente);

                        } else if (columna[0].split(".").length - 1 == 4) {//PARTIDAS-----------------------------------------------
                            id_partida_in = columna[0];
                            partida_in = columna[1];

                            //Se arregla el input del id de la partida
                            id_input =
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_partida" name="id_partida_ek[]" req="" value="' +
                                id_partida_in +
                                '">';
                            id_partida = label_partida + i_div_2 + id_input + f_div;

                            id_partidactual = id_partida;
                            //Se arregla el input del frente
                            partida_input =
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="partida" name="partida[]" req="" value="' +
                                partida_in +
                                '">';
                            partida = i_div_3 + partida_input + f_div_4;

                            partidaactual = id_partidactual + partida;

                            //$(".partidas").append(id + partida);s
                        }
                        else if (columna[0] != "") {//CONCEPTOS-----------------------------------------------
                            var siguienterow = rows[index + 1].split("\t");
                            if (siguienterow[0] == "") {
                                if (previousrow != "") {
                                    concepto_in = columna[0] + " (Apartado: " + previousrow + ") ";
                                } else {
                                    concepto_in = columna[0];
                                }

                                //Se arregla el input del id de la concepto
                                id_input =
                                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_concepto" name="id_concepto_ek[]" req="" value="' +
                                    concepto_in +
                                    '">';
                                concepto = label_concepto + i_div_2 + id_input + f_div_4;

                                conceptoactual = concepto;
                            } else {
                                previousrow = columna[0];
                            }
                        }
                        else if (columna[0] == "" && columna[1] != "") {//PARAMETROS-----------------------------------------------
                            var siguienterow = rows[index + 1].split("\t");
                            if (siguienterow[0].split(".").length - 1 == 3) {
                                hr = '<hr>';
                            }
                            parametro_in = columna[1];

                            //Se arregla el input del id de la parametro
                            id_input =
                                '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_parametro" name="id_parametro_ek[]" req="" value="' +
                                parametro_in +
                                '">';
                            parametro = conceptoactual + label_parametro + i_div_5 + id_input + f_div_5;


                            //$(".parametros").append(id);
                        }

                        if (id_frente == "") {
                            $(".frentes").append(i_group +
                                id_frente +
                                frente +
                                id_partida +
                                partida +
                                parametro +
                                f_group);
                        } else {
                            $(".frentes").append(hr + i_group + id_frente + frente + id_partida + partida + parametro + f_group);
                        }


                        id_frente = "";
                        frente = "";
                        id_partida = "";
                        partida = "";
                        concepto = "";
                        parametro = "";
                    }
                });

        });
});
```

View code:

```
<div class="card-header h4">
    Index
    <a asp-action="Guardar" class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-right" type="submit" title="Guardar 
    datos"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></a>
    <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-light btn-sm float-right" title="Crear nueva persona"><i 
    class="fas fa-redo"></i></a>
</div>


<div class="card-body">
    <label class="text-gray-800" id="div_cargar">Cargar datos aquí:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="excel" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <form asp-action="Guardar">
            <div class="frentes">

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything generated from the javascript goes into div class "frentes".

Comment: you'll want to create a class/model in the controller that matches your inputs. (So you can bind it)  ASP.NET will map the arrays via indexes... rows would be indexed items of a List of a class. Columns would be attributes of the Class you are creating a list of... ex: <input type = 'text' id="ClassListName_0_ClassName_AttributeName"> would be for the first item in your List<ClassName>.

Comment: @pcalkins I wrote this for the id and name attributes for the input: id="ListaPartidas_'+index+'_Partidas_Partida" but in the controller the list is null, am I missing something?

Comment: for the 'name' use: name="ListaPartidas["+index+"].Partidas.Partida".  The format is different than what the HTMLHelpers would produce for the id attribute... Use [BindProperty] attribute for the list in the controller.  I'm thinking the framework will use the name to bind to...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IFormCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformcollection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) class to handle the form submission.

Something like:

```
[HttpPost] // assuming you will be posting
public ActionResult YourActionMethod(IFormCollection data)
{
    // if you want to iterate
    foreach (var keyValuePair in data)
    {
        ...
    }
    // or if you want to get by form control name
    var name = data["name"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. As per the error message, please use IFormCollection instead.

Comment: Already tried IFormCollection but everything is in 0 and Results View throws:  "Enumeration yielded no results". Am I missing something?

Comment: When you submit, check the request from the browser in developer tools network tab to make sure that the data is being sent correctly.

Comment: Nothing is being sent